# Why do I get clipping when using tanh activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I implemented a rather simple MLP NN as a part of my project. I'm just testing it on a sinusoid right now and I expect this network's output to follow the sinusoid without issues.

Some network details:
32 input nodes
10 hidden nodes
I use tanh activation functions in both layers

I trained it using both BP and Prediction Error Algorithm and I see the same issue - I get a clipping of the tip of the function. Here is an image to illustrate:
[image: Clipped image]

If I make the target sinusoid with an amplitude of 0.9, it works fine:
[image: Good prediction image]

I have tried to crank up the learning rate up to 0.5, but it doesn't help (it just looks noisier). I think it's something I'm missing in my derivatives perhaps.

Here are my update equations (please ignore absence of transposes):
$$
y = tanh(H*tanh(Wx));
$$
$$
e = y - y_d
$$
$$
dH = \mu_1 * e * (1-tanh(H*tanh(Wx)^2)) * tanh(Wx)
$$
$$
dW = \mu_2 * x * e * H * (1-tanh(Wx)^2) * (1-tanh(H*tanh(Wx)^2))
$$
$$
H = H - dH
$$
$$
W = W - dW
$$

I know it does the clip because it doesn't reach a value of tanh that would output 1, (because tanh is nonlinear). Maybe I should squish my activation function to make it narrower?

That's it... Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be as simple as the fact that tanh becomes non-linear as it starts to flatten out approaching the value 1?